# Expressing weakness of alleged reasons for something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Let's take the sentence

**Sentence**. *Jim was detained on a slim ground that he was seen with Bob two days ago.*

The idea is to say that the justification for Jim's detention is weak, and I wanted to express it using the phrase 'on a slim ground'. However, having checked both google ngrams and google search, I found that the phrase 'on a slim ground' and its alternative 'on slim grounds' are not popular at all, so it is probably incorrect to use them.

**Question**. Is it true that the sentence at hand is not correct, and if so, how to replace 'on a slim ground' to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression using the plural **grounds** is approximately twice as popular today as the singular **ground**.

However, Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that **detained on the ground** is much older than the plural version and until the turn of the millennium, was also much more popular.

However, it's always **detained on THE grounds** and not **on a ground**.

So if you change the indefinite to the definite article, yes, your sentence is grammatical. As to the use of slim, it's one of a number of adjectives that could be used to indicate that there was little evidence to justify his detention.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=detained+on+the+grounds+that%2Cdetained+on+the+ground+that&year